# construct and print elements of a Binary Tree (unbalanced binary tree), from left to right, and from bottom-up

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, tree-traversal

please let me know how to achieve the following:

I have a binary tree, which is unbalanced, having both the left & right sub trees. I have to print the values of nodes of that unbalanced binary tree in the sequence

(i) from left to right,
(ii) from bottom to up, and 
(iii) also the data structure which will be used & its memory management or memory allocation.

What initially I thought is that will go for level-order-traversal, en-queue the elements, and then print and de-queue the queue.

Your help with example code, pseudo code, algorithm is highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Not intend to offend. I think you'd better first try what you think and then ask for a solution when getting trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of an unbalanced binary tree using C++.  The data carried in each node
is just a simple integer value (along with the management data of left and right child pointers and a depth for the level of the node).

Hopefully this shows how an insert visits nodes in the tree until it finds the proper place to insert a new node into the tree.

The left sub-tree contains values that are less than the current node.  So if the current node contains a value of 9 then the left sub-tree from that node is made up of nodes whose value is less than 9.

The right sub-tree contains value that are greater than the current node.  So if the current node contains a value of 9 then the right sub-tree from that node is made up of nodes whose value is greater than 9.

As you visit each node if you want to find a value that is greater than the value of the
current node then traverse the right sub-tree. If you want to find a value that is less than the value of the current node then traverse the left sub-tree.

```
// tree_data.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

// VS2005 standard include for precompiled headers, etc.
#include "stdafx.h"

// C++ iostream header for standard output in namespace std::
#include <iostream>

// An unbalanced, ordered binary tree
// Left subtree are items less than the node value.
// Right subtree are items greater than the node value.

// The items are in order from left most leaf to the right most leaf
// however the left and right subtrees may be unbalanced meaning not the same
// depth depending on the order of inserts.  In other words if there are
// a large number of consecutive inserts with decreasing values the
// result will be a tree whose root is the first value inserted with a
// long left tree of decreasing values and no right hand tree at all.

struct TreeNode {
    TreeNode *pLeft;    // node that is less than the current node
    TreeNode *pRight;   // node that is greater than the current node
    int    iValue;      // value for this node
    int    iDepth;      // depth of this node in the tree, number of levels
};

typedef TreeNode *TreeHead;

const TreeHead emptyTree = 0;


// Since we use new to allocate tree nodes, the InsertNode () function could
// conceivably throw a memory allocation exception.
void InsertNode (int iValue, TreeHead &pTree)
{
    TreeNode TreeHeadInit = {emptyTree, emptyTree, iValue, 0};

    if (pTree == emptyTree) {
        // initialize the tree with this first item and return
        pTree = new TreeNode;
        *pTree = TreeHeadInit;
        return;
    }

    // Tree is not empty so lets find the place to put this new item to
    // be inserted.  We traverse the tree until we find the correct empty
    // spot in the tree and then we put it there.  If we come across the
    // value already in the tree then we do nothing and just return.
    TreeHead pTreeStruct = pTree;
    while (pTreeStruct != emptyTree) {
        // remember the depth of the current node as it will become the parent
        // node if we reach the outer most leaf and need to add a new node.
        TreeHeadInit.iDepth = pTreeStruct->iDepth;
        if (pTreeStruct->iValue == iValue) {
            // since we have found a node with the value specified then we
            // are done and we do nothing.
            return;  // do nothing
        } else  if (pTreeStruct->iValue < iValue) {
            if (pTreeStruct->pRight == emptyTree) {
                // we have reached the place where we need to add a new node to
                // extend the right tree with this greater value than the current
                // node contains.  allocate the node then break to initialize it.
                pTreeStruct = pTreeStruct->pRight = new TreeNode;
                break;
            }
            // the value to insert is greater than this node so we
            // traverse to the right where values greater than the
            // value of the current node are located.
            pTreeStruct = pTreeStruct->pRight;
        } else {
            if (pTreeStruct->pLeft == emptyTree) {
                // we have reached the place where we need to add a new node to
                // extend the left tree with this greater value than the current
                // node contains.  allocate the node then break to initialize it.
                pTreeStruct = pTreeStruct->pLeft = new TreeNode;
                break;
            }
            // the value to insert is less than this node so we
            // traverse to the left where values less than the
            // value of the current node are located.
            pTreeStruct = pTreeStruct->pLeft;
        }
    }

    // update this new node that has been added to the tree and
    // set its depth to be one more than the depth of its parent node.
    TreeHeadInit.iDepth++;
    *pTreeStruct = TreeHeadInit;
    return;
}

// print the tree starting with the lowest value to the highest value.
// for each node we want to print out the left item which is lower than
// the node's value and then the right item which is higher than the
// node's value.
void PrintTreeInOrder (TreeHead pTree)
{
    if (pTree != emptyTree) {
        PrintTreeInOrder (pTree->pLeft);
        std::cout << "  value " << pTree->iValue << " depth " << pTree->iDepth << std::endl;
        PrintTreeInOrder (pTree->pRight);
    }
}

// print the tree from the root element indenting the printed lines to give an
// idea as to a diagram of the tree and how the nodes are sequenced.
void PrintTreeInDepth (TreeHead pTree)
{
    if (pTree != emptyTree) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pTree->iDepth; i++) std::cout << "|..";
        std::cout << " value " << pTree->iValue << " depth " << pTree->iDepth;
        if (pTree->pLeft != emptyTree) {
            std::cout << " left " << pTree->pLeft->iValue << " ";
        } else {
            std::cout << " left NULL ";
        }
        if (pTree->pRight != emptyTree) {
            std::cout << " right " << pTree->pRight->iValue << " ";
        } else {
            std::cout << " right NULL ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        PrintTreeInDepth (pTree->pLeft);
        PrintTreeInDepth (pTree->pRight);
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TreeHead myTree = emptyTree;

    // this is the first insert so will be the root of the unbalanced tree
    InsertNode (9, myTree);

    // now insert several items in decending order
    InsertNode (8, myTree);
    InsertNode (6, myTree);
    InsertNode (5, myTree);
    InsertNode (3, myTree);
    InsertNode (2, myTree);

    // now insert some other nodes haphazardly
    InsertNode (12, myTree);
    InsertNode (4, myTree);
    InsertNode (1, myTree);
    InsertNode (22, myTree);
    InsertNode (16, myTree);
    InsertNode (18, myTree);
    InsertNode (17, myTree);
    InsertNode (7, myTree);
    InsertNode (13, myTree);
    InsertNode (14, myTree);
    InsertNode (15, myTree);

    std::cout << "In order print" << std::endl;
    PrintTreeInOrder (myTree);
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Depth diagram from Root using left traversal" << std::endl;
    PrintTreeInDepth (myTree);
    return 0;
}
```

The output from the main which prints out the tree after inserting nodes looks like the
following.  This output first shows the in order traversal which lists the values of the
nodes in order from smallest to largest.  The next output gives an idea as to the structure
of the unbalanced tree showing how the left sub-tree from the root element is longer and has a greater number of levels than the right sub-tree.  You can also see from the second set of output which node contains which values.  For instance the node whose value is 6 has as its left child a node whose value is 5 and has as its right child a node whose value is 7.

```
In order print
  value 1 depth 6
  value 2 depth 5
  value 3 depth 4
  value 4 depth 5
  value 5 depth 3
  value 6 depth 2
  value 7 depth 3
  value 8 depth 1
  value 9 depth 0
  value 12 depth 1
  value 13 depth 4
  value 14 depth 5
  value 15 depth 6
  value 16 depth 3
  value 17 depth 5
  value 18 depth 4
  value 22 depth 2


Depth diagram from Root using left traversal
 value 9 depth 0 left 8  right 12
|.. value 8 depth 1 left 6  right NULL
|..|.. value 6 depth 2 left 5  right 7
|..|..|.. value 5 depth 3 left 3  right NULL
|..|..|..|.. value 3 depth 4 left 2  right 4
|..|..|..|..|.. value 2 depth 5 left 1  right NULL
|..|..|..|..|..|.. value 1 depth 6 left NULL  right NULL
|..|..|..|..|.. value 4 depth 5 left NULL  right NULL
|..|..|.. value 7 depth 3 left NULL  right NULL
|.. value 12 depth 1 left NULL  right 22
|..|.. value 22 depth 2 left 16  right NULL
|..|..|.. value 16 depth 3 left 13  right 18
|..|..|..|.. value 13 depth 4 left NULL  right 14
|..|..|..|..|.. value 14 depth 5 left NULL  right 15
|..|..|..|..|..|.. value 15 depth 6 left NULL  right NULL
|..|..|..|.. value 18 depth 4 left 17  right NULL
|..|..|..|..|.. value 17 depth 5 left NULL  right NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have already understand the algorithm. just keep in mind that the tree is unbalanced, a normal recursion implementation may cause StackOverflow.