# Binary Search Tree Issue in C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

i am creating a binary search tree, and here is my code for the TreeDB.cpp file:

```
TreeDB::TreeDB()
{
    root = NULL;
}

bool TreeDB::insert(DBentry * _entry)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = new TreeNode(_entry);
        root->setLeft(NULL);
        root->setRight(NULL);
        cout <<"Inserted at root";
    }
    else
    {
        insert_helper(root,_entry);
    }
}

bool TreeDB::insert_helper(TreeNode *curr, DBentry * _entry)
{
 string temp1 = curr->getEntry()->getName();
 string temp2 = _entry-> getName();

 if(temp1 == temp2)
 {
     cout <<"Error: entry already exists"<<endl;
     delete _entry;
     return false;
 }

 else if(temp1<temp2)
 {
     if(curr->getRight() == NULL)
     {

         curr->setRight(new TreeNode(_entry));
         cout << "Set right";
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
         insert_helper(curr->getRight(),_entry);
     }
 }
 else
 {
     if(curr->getLeft() == NULL)
     {
         curr->setLeft(new TreeNode(_entry));
         cout <<"Set Left";
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
         insert_helper(curr->getLeft(),_entry);
     }
 }
}
```

and my header file is Tree.h:

```
class TreeDB {

private:
   TreeNode* root;
   int probesCount;


public:

TreeDB();

~TreeDB();
bool insert(DBentry* newEntry); 
bool insert_helper(TreeNode*curr,DBentry*_entry);


};
```

And i am also creating the object of this tree in main like so:

```
TreeDB Tree;
while (!lineStream.eof())
{
    if (command == "insert")
    {
        unsigned int address;
        string name;
        bool active;
        lineStream >> name >> address >> active;
        DBentry * a = new DBentry(name,address,active);
        Tree.insert(a);
    }
```

However, every time i try to insert something, it always inserts at the root, so either the previous one never gets saved or it gets deleted after each insert. Any hints as to how i can resolve this issue?

Comment: Take a look at this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965753/construct-and-print-elements-of-a-binary-tree-unbalanced-binary-tree-from-lef

Comment: Debug your code, with printf if you don't know the debugger.  You're trying to trace the code path taken by a wrong insert.  Once you see where it breaks, you're very close to fixing it.

Comment: The program isn't complete to reproduce the problem. Based on the code it seems as if it shouldn't always insert at the root: what is the input you try to run it with? I assume you enter multiple values with same run? Also, do **not** use `eof()` to test if you input worked: you need to test after your input, e.g.: `if (lineStram >> name >> address >> active) { ... }`

Comment: Actually, the program always has undefined behavior: you declared your function to return `bool` but you typically don't return anything; you sometimes return something but that isn't good enough.